# Trying to Replace h2's with Anchor Links within the_content() dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, preg-replace

I am trying to create a side anchor navigation that will build out the side nav for every h2 tag header. I have the side nav portion working just the way I want it to. It pulls the `h2` out of the wordpress `the_content` and creates an anchor link and replaces the value of the h2 with a string such as (#-this-is-an-anchor) if the first h2 in the_content is This Is An Anchor.

The part Im having a problem with is wrapping `the_content` h2's with the anchor id to connect to the side nav values. The below code is to display the body content, which is what Im having issues with.

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content();
preg_replace_callback( '@<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>@',function($matches)  {
    global $h;
    $h = array();
    $h[] = $matches[1];
    return'';
    }, $content);
    $anchor_div = '';
    foreach($h as $h_tag) {
       $anchor_div = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($h_tag));
    }
    echo preg_replace('@<h2.*?>(.*?)<\/h2>@','<div id="'. $anchor_div .'"><h2>'. $h_tag.'</h2></div>', $content);
                        
    ?>
```

Now this is working, however only the last h2 value is being displayed as the h2 replacement and the anchor link. You can see in the image what Im trying to do. This works if I wrap the `preg_replace` within the foreach statement, but duplicates everything. So having it outside is showing the right amount of content, but like I said, the last anchor value is only showing in the body.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you don't do the replacement in the loop where you create `$anchor_div` - then all your h2 will get wrapped in a div with the exact same id, so the whole thing won't work. But I don't really get what you are doing there to begin with - why are you using `preg_replace_callback` _and_ `preg_replace`?

Comment: I'd really rather to this on the client side, using JavaScript. This additional anchor navigation is not _that_ essential that it would break the site if JS was not enabled; and the advantage is that you can already work with DOM methods there, instead of having to let lose regular expressions on HTML (which is a rather bad idea to begin with.)

Comment: Right, yeah outside the loop is where Im running into the issue. I would use JS, but I wanted to try to keep it within PHP, so I dont have to use inline JS, since the content that will be triggering the anchoring will be generated within the WYSIWYG.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/kN8TA - $new is your input text with the IDs added to the h2, and $anchors is an array of the h2 text contents and the resulting ID values, that you can use to create your navigation.

Comment: This is great. thank you. I just changed the `str_replace` to include `strtolower($matches[2])` and it worked. Please post your code as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$anchors = [];
$new = preg_replace_callback('@(<h2.*?)>(.*?)<\/h2>@',function($matches) use(&$anchors) {
    $anchor = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($matches[2]));
    $anchors[] = [$matches[2], $anchor];
    return $matches[1] . ' id="' . $anchor . '">' . $matches[2] . '</h2>';
}, $text);
```

This adds the id attribute to the h2 elements, and in $anchors you find the original h2 text contents and the used ids, so that you can create your navigation based on that.